# Java Velocity foreach loop

Tags: java, foreach, velocity

I have an ArrayList that im populating within java and passing it off to a velocity template for consumption. Now when i try iterating the list and creating a 'comma' separated string from the list, Im observing an erratic behavior.

The following is my code

```
> #set($list_str="")
> #foreach($item in $list)
>     #set($list_str=$!list_str+$!item+",")
> #end
```

Now i see that my variable $list_str has all the elements of the list but at the end the variable name of the iterator '$!item' is also being appended.

`So, say my list has [0,1,2,3,4], my end result(value of $list_str) is [0,1,2,3,4],$!item,`

Im not sure if this is because of a null reference from within the list being populated and being passed to the velocity template.

Any pointers towards fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is not caused by something else somewhere? Can you output all the intermediate results for each iteration of the loop? Also, where are the brackets from in the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a quick check and this seems to be because of a null value in your ArrayList.

For an ArrayList populated as below --

```
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
        list.add("try");
        list.add("to");
        list.add("figure");
        list.add("it");
```

and with a velocity code as below --

```
#foreach($iter in $list)
    $!iter
    #set($list_str=$!list_str+$!iter+",")
#end
$!list_str
```

I get the following output --

```
try
    to
    figure
    it
try,to,figure,it,
```

which seems to be as expected.

Now when i populate my Arraylist as follows --

```
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
        list.add("try");
        list.add("to");
        list.add("figure");
        list.add("it");
        list.add(null);
```

and with the same velocty code as above, i get the following output --

```
try
    to
    figure
    it

try,to,figure,it,$!iter,
```

So , im guessing that you need to add a null check somewhere in your code to avoid this.

Thanks
p1nG

PS: As pointed out by @Thilo Im not sure where the brackets are from, not sure if this is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use the velocity tools to do this
eg

```
#set($display = $utils.getClass().forName("org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.DisplayTool").newInstance())
#set($myArray=["nando","bob","don"])
$display.list($myArr,",")
```

Thats it the result will be nando,bob,don
if you dont include the second parameter in the list method you get
nando,bob and don